# Makefile for two compilers and different optimization techniques

Tags: gcc, makefile

I have been trying to compile a single c program with two different compilers icc and gcc with different optimization techniques using this code.

I tried using the following code in the Makefile.

```
 output: prog3.o
    gcc prog3.o -o2 output
    gcc prog3.o -o3 output
    icc prog3.o -o2 output
 prog3.o: prog3.c
    gcc -c prog3.c
    gcc -c prog3.c
    icc -c prog3.c

 clean:
    rm *.o output
```

I got an output by executing the cmd, ./output

i got output for one round of execution only. 
for example, :

```
 ./output 
Total time taken by CPU for Matrix addition looping over row: 1.210000
Total time taken by CPU for Matrix addition looping over column: 6.480000
```

Is it possible to have a single makefile that compiles both icc and gcc with different optimization techniques. I read online on many methods to create makefiles for gcc & g++ or for multiple c prog.s but not my problem.

Comment: do you mean you want to use one makefile to generate different output with different options, like opt level?

Comment: You are creating 3 object files, with the same name and no optimization, and over-write them so that only the last one exists. Then you try to link the single remaining object into an 3 executables with the same name, which get over-written again and only the last one remains. The optimization you put has no effect on the linking stage. Your compilation is equivalent to `icc prog3.c -o output` if I'm not mistaken.

Answer (score 0):

At a first: 
You can compile and link a single-file-program in one step, at least with the compilers I know.

```
 g++ -o exe program.cpp
```

gives the executable exe.

The first, easy makefile for your problem could look so:

```
all: progG1 progG2 progI1 progI2

progG1: source.cpp
    g++ -O1 -o progG1 source.cpp

progG2: source.cpp
    g++ -O2 -o progG2 source.cpp
```

and so on

You can improve it with some marcros

```
src = source.cpp

all: progG1 progG2 progI1 progI2

progG1: $(src)
    gcc -O1 -o $@ $<
```

and so on.

> $@ is the target, $< is the only prerequisite; $^ stand for all  prerequisites, if there are two or more.

---

In the first row of the makefile the target all is a dummy. It forces make to build the
prerequisites progGo1, progGo2, progI1 and progI2. Each an executable, build in different ways from the same source-file.

Then we give for each different way, you want to choose to compile, a different rule. In other words: A different way to build an executable from the source-file is a different recipe, therefore it forms a different rule.

The make utility can build different executables from different source-files with the same pattern (using %-letter) rule, but you are trying the contrary thing.